# VBA Array determine where to put values next

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba, recordset

I have a recordset from en SQL server. I don't know the exact amount of data I need to retrieve, hence I have created a dynamic array.
What I need to do, is to seperate and sort data when I put it in the array. But I don't know what best practice on this will be.

E.g. I have set of data with a customer ID in one column and revenue in the second. Lets say I only have 2 customers and have a list like the one below:

```
Customer ID     Revenue
1               604
2               669
2               732
2               629
1               897
2               530
```

I would then like my array to have two dimensions (customer 1 and 2) and have a maximum lenght that matches with the maximum amount of purchases one customer has made. In this case, customer 2 have made four purchases and customer 1 have made two. Therefore my ideal array would be something like this: myArray(1 to 2, 4).

How will I do this best?

Then after I have defined my array, I would like to populate it with my data, but the data is not sorted, so how can I determine in what place I should put the data next? If that makes sence?

For example my initial thought was to run through the dataset and do something like this:

```
i = 1

do until dataset.eof
if dataset.field("customerid") = 1 then 
   myArray(1, i) = dataset.field("customerid").value
else if dataset.field("customerid") = 2 then
   myArray(1, i) = dataset.field("customerid").value
end if

i = i + 1
dataset.movenext
loop
```

This is all fine and dandy, until the customer ID changes. If the first to rows are customer 1 then the data would be placed in myArray(1, 1) and myArray(1, 2). But then if the customer ID on the next row i customer 2, the first entry for customer 2 will be in myArray(2, 3) and not in myArray(2, 1) as I will desire.
Also with this, I will exceed the limits of the array if I have the array defined as per my first question :-)

Does this all make sense?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Getting it into some kind of array is only half the story: what are you going to do *after* that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scripting dictionary with the customer id as the key and an array of revenues as the value.

Untested:

```
dim dict as object, id, rev, tmp, k
set dict = createobject("scripting.dictionary")

do until dataset.eof
    id = dataset.fields("customerid").Value
    rev = dataset.fields("revenue").Value

    if dict.exists(id) then
        tmp = dict(id)
        ub = ubound(tmp)+1
        redim preserve tmp(0 to ub)
        tmp(ub) = rev
        dict(id) = tmp
    else
        dict(id) = Array(rev)
    end if

    dataset.movenext
loop

for each k in dict
    debug.print k, join(dict(k),", ") 
next k
```

Comment: How would that compare with using a Class and a collection object?

Comment: I would say it's more or less similar. What is "best" really depends on what the OP wants to do.  I tend to lean towards the dictionary more than collections because I often want fast key-based access to items, but horses for courses always applies...

Comment: This solution is so much more smooth than what my initial though was. It works like a charm - thanks a  lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that arrays are not the best data structure for this goal. I would use a collection of classes. That gives great flexibility in both storing and sorting data. As an example, I created the following:

-in the worksheet (as data source, to replace your recordset):

[image: data_source]

-Code module Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub jzz()

Dim Customers As Collection
Dim cust As cls_customer
Dim i As Long
Dim arr() As Long

Set Customers = New Collection
i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = vbNullString
    'check if the customer is already in the collection:'
    For Each cust In Customers
        If cust.id = Cells(i, 1) Then Exit For
    Next cust
    'check if the customer was found; if not, create new and add to collection'
    If cust Is Nothing Then
        Set cust = New cls_customer
        cust.id = Cells(i, 1)
        Customers.Add cust
    End If
    cust.Revenue = Cells(i, 2)
    i = i + 1
Loop

For Each cust In Customers
    Debug.Print cust.id, cust.Revenue_count
Next cust

Set Customers = Nothing

End Sub
```

-Class module cls_customer:

```
Option Explicit


Public id As Long
Private p_revenue_collection As Collection

Public Property Let Revenue(value As Long)
    'accepts a long (value) and adds it to the collection'
    p_revenue_collection.Add value
End Property

Public Property Get Revenue_count() As Long
    Revenue_count = p_revenue_collection.Count
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set p_revenue_collection = New Collection
End Sub
```

The class holds only the revenue_count property, which returns the amount of entries in the collection, but you can add your own properties at will to return sorted data etc.